# dont display my hypertext link

Tags: html, typescript

I have a descriptor component and in my tag, it should not display a hypertext link. But it's displaying the content like below which I don't want.

```
description: 'A box that contains a label with multiple headings. Designed to be used inside a' + ' <a href="#/components/mae-box-layout">box-layout</a>.',
```

And he display me that :

```
A box that contains a label. Designed to be used inside a <a href="#/components/mae-box-layout">box-layout</a>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the href as a string. Try:

```
'A box that contains a label with multiple headings. Designed to be used inside a ' + <a href="#/components/mae-box-layout">box-layout</a>.
```